# Is it possible to automate an RDP session using Selenium or any other tool?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, rdp

1. I am automating a web application which downloads an .rdp file on clicking a link.
2. I have used Selenium and performed the task of downloading the .rdp file.
3. Now is there any way to execute this file from the downloaded folder and perform a some simple task like opening Notepad?

I have written the Selenium automation code in Java and using TestNG framework.

Comment: You can execute the file with pure `Java` using `ProcessBuilder` and `Process`. You can also open the notepad with java. There are a lot of tutorials online on how to do it

Comment: Can you please share a link to those tutorial...also just to add more info...when i open the rdp file a new rdp session of a different machine opens up. Thanks!! So will your provided solution with ProcessBuilder in such scenario?

Comment: You can use Sikuli for automating desktop steps, or to execute shell command for opening and connecting RDP